# CakePHP 1.3 PHP Strict Warnings

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx

I know there's a LOT of stuff written here about this but we're running a CakePHP 1.3 on the newest PHP version on our Debian server. Right now there's multiple people using the system and I just had to delete a 17GB error.log from the server. It keeps pushing PHP Strict Standards error messages to it even though I've supressed the messages from the CakePHP /cake/bootstrap.php by adding the ~E_STRICT and I've thought about adding this..

```
Configure::write('Error', array(
'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError',
'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT,
'trace' => true
));
```

.. to the /app/core.php but I'm afraid to go do it on a live operation.

Why cannot I suppress these messages from the bootstrap.php or is the core.php the only way even though the Configure::write('Error'), array()); is commented out in there?

Comment: what is the error/warning it writes on the log form bootstrap.php?

Comment: Mostly now: [error] 9768#0: *6345 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method CakeLog::handleError() should not be called statically in /home/user/public_html/cake/libs/model/connection_manager.php on line 291. After this it's just PHP Strict Standards: Same stuff for 10 rows and it goes on and on.

Answer (score 0):

```
Configure::write('log', E_WARNING);
```

This would log only warning and fatal errors. If you want to disable error logging, this should work:

```
Configure::write('log', false);
```

Comment: Does not help. Still writing PHP messages.

Comment: Error logging should be disabled with Configure::write('log', false); only when  Configure::write('debug', 0);

Comment: I've set the debug to 0, as is for production mode, but the log false works. The only downside of it is it disables _all_ error messages, even E_ERROR and E_WARNING. I just need to disable E_STRICT.